# Icebourn Gauntlet + Black Cleaver

Tags: league-of-legends

If one would buy Icebourn Gauntlet and Black Cleaver, would everyone's armor get reduced that got hit by the Black Cleaver?
I know it works for the Spirit of the Elder Lizard because there is a clear particle animation.
I basically want to know this for Ezreal, but I guess it goes for every champion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes every champion that suffers damage from the AOE effect will take a single stack. Note however that there will be only one stack applied to the main target that procs the on-hit effect. This works similar to the on-hit of Ravenous Hydra or Tiamat ([Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/The_Black_Cleaver)).

As the description of black cleaver says it will apply a stack for every time you deal Physical damage. This counts for Items, Spells and auto attack but it does not apply for on hit effects on a single target. However spells that hit multiple times in a short amount of time will apply a stack for every single time they hit a champion. This is the main reason why BC is so popular on champions like Wukong (Ultimate) and Pantheon (E-Spell).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I knew about the ticks (like Wu-Kong's ulti or MF's ulti), but now I know if the cleaver is a legit choice in some situations on my Blueish Ezreal build.

Comment: Sort of, but keep in mind as an Ezreal you're there to do damage yourself, not to buff your bruisers' damage.

Comment: Well still. BC is a pretty decent Item on Ezreal. It's just as good (if not better) as LW because of the CDR and more AD on the item.

Comment: I know how to build Ezreal, trust me. I main him for a loooong time now. :)